# Como atribuir posições a um vetor dentro de um loop “do while”?

Tags: c, array

Estou tentando criar um programa que converte números decimais -de 0 até 255 -, que o usuário digita, para binários. Já consigo converter normalmente e mostrar o resultado invertido, o que não resolve. Pensei então em atribuir a cada `loop` do `do while` uma posição em um vetor (banana) usando o `for`, de modo que eu possa depois inverter ele usando o `strrev()`. Porém, não consegui.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
#define len 8

int main(void) {
    int nusr, resto;
    long int banana[len];
    scanf("%i", &nusr);
    if (0<=nusr && nusr<=255){
        (float)nusr;
        nusr/2;
        do {
            resto = nusr%2;
            nusr = (nusr/2);
            printf("%i", resto);
        }
        while ((int)nusr!=0);
        return 0;
    }
    else if (nusr) {
        printf ("Numero invalido!");
        return 0;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: As linhas `(float)nusr;` e `nusr / 2;` não estão atribuindo o valor a nenhuma variável, então podem ser removidas. A divisão de dois `int`'s sempre é outro `int` então no `while` não precisa fazer cast, pode ser apenas `while (nusr != 0);`. Se tem o mesmo `return 0` dentro do `if` e do `else`, então poderia tirá-los e ter apenas o `return 0` no final. No `else`, o `if(nusr)` pode ser removido. E vc pode guardar os dígitos no array `banana` e ao imprimir, percorra-o ao contrário (`for (int i = len - 1; i >= 0; i--) imprime banana[i]` - mas mude o nome pra algo melhor, como `digitos`) :-)

Comment: Muito obrigado pelas dicas! Só mais uma coisa: coloquei o for fora do "do while", assim o loop ficar correto, mas não sei como escrever. Tentei digitos[i]=resto; mas não consigo atribuir os valores, aparece (null)...

Comment: Vc tem que [edit] a pergunta e colocar o código que tentou, senão não tem como saber onde está o erro. De qualquer forma, uma sugestão: https://ideone.com/8Ov5tT

Answer (score 1):

> criar um programa que converte números decimais -de 0 até 255 -, que o usuário digita, para binários. Já consigo converter normalmente e mostrar o resultado invertido, o que não resolve. Pensei então em atribuir a cada loop do "do while" uma posição em um vetor (banana) usando o for, de modo que eu possa depois inverter ele usando o strrev(). Porém, não consegui. Algum dos senhores poderia me dar uma luz para resolver esse problema?

Não estaria complicando demais as coisas? Trata-se de um byte. Não precisa inverter nada. A notação posicional já resolveu isso no sistema hindu nos primeiros séculos d.c, o mesmo sistema usado até hoje.

### sobre seu programa

```
   int nusr, resto;
    long int banana[len];
    scanf("%i", &nusr);
    if (0<=nusr && nusr<=255){
```

- teste sempre o retorno de scanf(). Qual o propósito de seguir se não ler nada? Qual vai ser o valor de `nusr`?
- se vai ler algo entre 0 e 255 inclusive, porque está lendo em um `int` para depois testar o que leu? Não era melhor ler um `unsigned char` afinal? Aquilo que tem um valor entre 0 e 255 inclusive e que ocupa... um byte, no popular oito bits? Esta lendo em um valor que em geral tem até 4 bytes e um sinal, para depois testar se é positivo e se cabe em um byte só. Deixe o compilador trabalhar por você:

[![Direto do manual][1]][1]

Isso quer dizer que basta você usar o especificador `"%hhu"` ao chamar `scanf()`

### 2 Exemplos em C

**Convertendo um byte para binário**

O enunciado é vago, se é que você tem um. Então vamos imaginar a saída no formato

```
    nnn em binario = 12345678
```

**Como em**

```
    128 em binario = 10000000
      1 em binario = 00000001
      0 em binario = 00000000
    255 em binario = 11111111
```

Cada bit da string vale, claro, 0 ou 1. Acontece que eles são a representação do valor digitado. Em decimal, 123 é 1 x 100 + 2 X 10 + 3...

O que tem cada posição, em binário? Os bits valem a potência de 2 correspondente, 1,2,4,8,16,32,64 e 128, ou seja

> `bit i = 1 << i`

Além disso:

- em C uma expressão vale 0 se for falsa e 1 se for verdadeira
- o valor de `'1'` é `1 + '0'`

E assim não precisa de nada mais para converter o byte para binário numa hipotética string de `0` e `1` declarada

```
    char binario[] = "12345678"; // 8 bits
```

E

```
  binario[7] = '0' + ((N &   1) != 0)
  binario[6] = '0' + ((N &   2) != 0)
  binario[5] = '0' + ((N &   4) != 0)
  binario[4] = '0' + ((N &   8) != 0)
  binario[3] = '0' + ((N &  16) != 0)
  binario[2] = '0' + ((N &  32) != 0)
  binario[2] = '0' + ((N &  64) != 0)
  binario[0] = '0' + ((N & 128) != 0)
```

#### Exemplo 1:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    unsigned char N = 0;
    char          binario[] = "12345678"; // 8 bits
    printf("Valor a converter para binario (entre 0 e 255 incl.) : ");
    int res = scanf("%hhu", &N); // o simples: byte sem sinal
    if ( res != 1 ) return -1;
    binario[7] = '0' + ((N &   1) != 0); // o bit 0 fica do lado direito
    binario[6] = '0' + ((N &   2) != 0); // porque e uma string
    binario[5] = '0' + ((N &   4) != 0);
    binario[4] = '0' + ((N &   8) != 0);
    binario[3] = '0' + ((N &  16) != 0);
    binario[2] = '0' + ((N &  32) != 0);
    binario[2] = '0' + ((N &  64) != 0);
    binario[0] = '0' + ((N & 128) != 0); // esse e o bit 7
    printf("\n\t%3d em binario = %s\n", N, binario);
    return 0;
}
```

Sem loops, sem funções exceto a leitura.

#### Outro exemplo, com loop

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    unsigned char N = 0;
    char          binario[] = "12345678"; // 8 bits
    printf("Valor a converter para binario (entre 0 e 255 incl.) : ");
    int res = scanf("%hhu", &N); // o simples: byte sem sinal
    if ( res != 1 ) return -1;
    for ( int i    = 0; i<8; i+=1)
        binario[7-i] = '0' + ((N & (1<<i)) != 0);
    printf("\n\t%3d em binario = %s\n", N, binario);
    return 0;
}
```

Um pouco mais curto.

```
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/prNBB.png
```